# Query based on referenced document's field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have 3 collections

```
Companies: [{name:'Lamy'}]
Pens : [name:'Safari', company:ref::companies]
Writing Samples :[{title:'Post title', pen:ref::pens }]
```

I want to get all writing samples from from a particular pen company.

Is it possible to filter based on field values in a referenced document or do I need to restructure my firestore?

Example

```
const company = db.collection('companies').doc(form.penCompany);
db.collection('samples').where('pen.company', '==', company)
```

My guess is no and that I need to restructure my DB to include the company information nested in the sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to restructure.  A query on a collection can't reference documents from other collections - there are no SQL-like joins.  Everything in the query must be in the same collection.  This means you might have to duplicate data between collections.  This is a common technique when working with NoSQL.  It's call "denomralization".

Comment: Thank you. I did just that. I'll try and use a cloud function to keep everything in sync :)